# SIGSTOP all proccesses, but stay awake

Tags: suspend

My computer has a hardware problem, causing it to break when sleeping(needs a hard reset). I would, however, still like to get some sort of low-power mode. is it possible to send a SIGSTOP to all proccesses, then half turn off the kernel? I would like it as replacement for suspend, so I also need a way to reverse it. I dont know exactly what the hardware peoblem is, but my laptop just starts beeping when you put it to sleep.

Comment: if `cat /sys/power/state` contains `freeze`, you can try `echo "freeze" > /sys/power/state`. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/states.txt

Comment: There may be power-related knobs to tune the suspend state in the BIOS settings that you may want to play with to see if that helps with your *hardware problem*.

Comment: @OliverKnodel thanks! could you post it as an answer so i can accept/upvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more sleep states the linux kernel supports, if you call:

```
cat /sys/power/state
```

the states on your computer will be printed. If this contains `freeze` you can try:

```
echo "freeze" > /sys/power/state
```

More Information about sleep states with the linux kernel:
[Sleep States](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/states.txt)

Answer (score 0):

To do that simply use `kill -SIGSTOP $(ps -o pid -ax --ppid $PPID)` this will stop all and every process. I advise you to not do that simply because there is no way to reverse this action other than restarting your computer as far as I'm aware.